# java stream with optional filter predicate

Tags: java, java-stream

Is this (version 1):

```
   public List<Task> getTasks(Set<Task> tasks, Predicate<? super Task> predicate) {
    var stream = tasks.stream();
    if (predicate != null) stream.filter(predicate);
    // is the stream filtered if predicate != null ?
    return stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

the same as this (version 2):

```
   public List<Task> getTasks(Set<Task> tasks, Predicate<? super Task> predicate) {
    var stream = tasks.stream();
    // do I must reassign the stream to have the filtering
    if (predicate != null) stream = stream.filter(predicate);
    return stream.collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

**EDIT:**

Only version 2 is correct, version 1 is incorrect.

**Related question:**

Is there a way to bypass an itermediate operation without using the solution of version 2? For example,

```
stream.filter(pred == null ? Void : predicate)
      .order(comparator == null ? Void : comparator);
```

Comment: no it is not the same, `stream.filter` returns a new instance of `Stream` so only the second snippet will work. You can even do something like this: `return tasks.stream().filter(t -> predicate == null || predicate.test(t)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

Comment: Docs of `filter` state: *Returns a stream consisting of the elements of this stream that match the given predicate. Returns: **the new stream***

Comment: @Lino or `.filter(p == null ? e -> true : p)`. That said, omitting an entire operation could possibly allow the the pipeline to be optimized (though probably not in the example shown).

Comment: Is there a way to bypass an itermediate operation without using my solution above? For example, `stream.filter(pred == null ? Void : predicate).order(comparator == null ? Void : comparator);`

Comment: @nimo23 Not from *within* the stream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No they are not the same. You have to do the re-assignment to Stream because filter doesn't mutate the underlying stream it creates a new Stream object. Very good question though.

Answer (score 1):

Answer [by @Jason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60951024/1746118) is to the point. While the first code block *does not `filter` out* anything since you do not update the existing `stream`, the second selectively returns the tasks based on a non-null predicate.

To complete the answer, you can simplify the code to

```
public List<Task> getTaskss(Set<Task> tasks, Predicate<? super Task> predicate) {
    return predicate == null ? new ArrayList<>(tasks) :
            tasks.stream().filter(predicate).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: I find this solution not better than using my **version 2**, because your solution has to do the the extra work of the filtering pipeline even if predicate is null. Would be better if java supports passing nulls within intermediate opertations leaving the java stream pipeline event untouched. But Java does not support passing nulls within intermediate operations..so we have to do some workaround..

Comment: @nimo23 The updated answer, given the current code in question simplifies things. Passing `null` values expected to be handled by the library would be really not feasible or a good idea if they can't be governed by the people consuming the API on the other hand.